# What is the bug inside this C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, virtualization

I believe It's C++ but it may be C? Its been a while since I looked at C++ so I didn't end up finding the bug. I was asked this question in an interview and didn't have an answer. I obviously didn't get the job but now I'm curious to find the answer.

```
#include<iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cerr<<"constructing Base " << this << std::endl;
        i = new int;
    }
    ~Base() {
        std::cerr<<"destroying Base " << this << std::endl;
        delete i;
    }
private
    int* i;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::cerr<<"constructing Dervied " << this << std::endl;
        d = new double;
    }
    ~Derived() {
        std::cerr<<"destroying Derived " << this << std::endl;
        delete d;
    }
private
    double* d;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using namespace std;
    int ret = 1;
    Base* thePtr = new Derived;
    delete thePtr;
    return ret;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is __not__ C code, that's what wrong with it Period.

Comment: Derived's destructor should be virtual

Comment: @SouravGhosh: actually the destructor of `Base` is not `virtual` so there is indeed an error.

Comment: Did you try to [compile it](http://ideone.com/MGQWMh)?

Comment: I think you didn't really miss out too much, if someone offered this as an example of C code, I'd run a mile - further more, if they offered it as an example of modern C++ code, I'd run a couple of hundred miles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Base`'s destructor is not virtual. This will leak the `Derived::d` pointer, at best.

Actually, it's undefined behaviour to delete a pointer of derived class through a base class pointer without virtual destructor (thanks to GManNickG)

Comment: This answer is almost correct. It has nothing to do with leaking: if you delete a derived class via a pointer to base, and the base does not have a virtual destructor, the result is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @juanchopanza: plain `new` & `delete` are 2 issues I see with this code. Why `new` & `delete` is being used here ?

Comment: @Destructor For example, copy and assignment are broken.

Answer (score 2):

You should mark `Base` class destructor as `virtual`. In your code `Base` class destructor isn't `virtual` & base class pointer is pointing to `Derived` class object so by default destructor will be called of `Base` class unless it is marked as `virtual`. This will leak dynamically allocated memory of  `Derived` class data member `d` & invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 2):

Let me make a list...

- `Base` destructor is not `virtual`.
- It's using raw pointers instead of smart pointers
- In fact, it doesn't need pointers, `new` and `delete` at all
- And therefore, it doesn't actually need destructors.
- Also `Derived` is spelled `Dervied`
- ... and it won't compile.

Comment: You also forgot to mention that code doesn't follow rule of three.

Comment: @Destructor or rule of five for C++11. But after you remove the pointers it doesn't need to :)

Answer (score 0):

Your base class destructor should be declared virtual, it looks like 
`cpp
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cerr<<"destroying Base " << this << std::endl;
        delete i;
    }`

you can find it here http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/virtual-destructors/

Virtual destructors are useful when you can delete an instance of a derived class through a pointer to base class:

> there is a major problem with the code above: the destructor for the "Derive" class does not get called at all when we delete `basePtr`,

The construction of derived object follow the construction rule but when we delete the "b" pointer(base pointer) we have found that only the base destructor is call.But this must not be happened.

To do the appropriate thing we have to make the base destructor virtual. it's similar to the run-time polymorphism, so that the compiler will find this is a base pointer but point to the derived class, and automatically bound derived class destructor for it

Comment: and then expected ':' after your `private`